# How to retrieve the sub values of a keyed item in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

How do I get the numbers from a, what? subindexed dictionary?  (I don't even know the right terms here).

Still a relative newbee here but this is my first pass at a dictionary and while I understand the very simple basic concept I'm missing how to access things.  My dictionary seems to hold the data I want it in the way I want it, but I'm fumbling around on how to access it.

Here's my code:

```
all_bone_keys[bone.GetName()][frame] = {"x":x[1], "y":y[1], "z":z[1]}
print (len(all_bone_keys["RL_Head"])
print (all_bone_keys["RL_Head"])
```

with these results (all fine):

```
2
{0: {'x': -0.4033583402633667, 'y': -0.08630772680044174, 'z': 0.4855811595916748}, 116: {'x': -0.13178503513336182, 'y': 0.3115540146827698, 'z': 0.2189643830060959}}
```

So all well and good -- I have the data as I want it, with the two frames showing my x,y,z.  I can read how many items for each bone just fine so I know how many frames are there, and I can even access the x, y and z values IF I know the frame numbers:

```
print (all_bone_keys["RL_Head"][116]["x"])
-0.13178503513336182
```

but how do I get the 116 in the first place? That's all I really want to know, is how to read those frame numbers so I can then access the data associated with them.

I've looked at tons of tutorials but don't seem to get it, as they nearly always show a dictionary example much simpler.  Any help would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by: `but how do I get the 116 in the first place?`

Comment: I mean, there are two values in there, a 0 and a 116 -- but how do I access those values?  I won't know up front which values are there but once I have those I can access the x, y and z (and I do know there are only two because printing len() returns that.  So I guess I'm asking how to cycle through the len of that particular key value).  For each bone_head there can be any number of frames, each with an x,y and z value.  This works fine -- and I can find out how many frames, but just not the frame number in order to get that x,y and z values.

Comment: You could do: `print(all_bone_keys["RL_Head"].keys())`

Comment: Great!  Except now I feel REALLY stupid -- I see where that shows me the keys, but how do I access each key separately?  I see that I can tell how many with len() but I am clearly such a newbee I don't get how to get each one at a time.

Comment: `for key in all_bone_keys["RL_Head"].keys(): # do something with the key`

Comment: Edit: AHHHH, okay, got it (a little more web searching.  But your answer was - if you'll excuse the expression -- the key.  I just had to do this: keys = all_bone_keys["RL_Head"].keys()
    for each in keys:
        print (each)  Edit: sorry, cross posted but THANKS SO MUCH for all the help (I was getting even more ancient as I tried things).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options, most of which can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

In your case:

- to get dictionary view of keys, as mentioned in comments:

  ```
  for frame in all_bone_keys["RL_Head"].keys():
      print(frame, all_bone_keys["RL_Head"][frame]["x"])
  ```
- to get both frame and coordinates at once (my favourite for most applications):

  ```
  for frame, coord in all_bone_keys["RL_Head"].items():
      print(frame, coord["x"])
  ```
- to ensure ordering of frames (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html):

  ```
  for frame in sorted(all_bone_keys["RL_Head"].keys()):
      print(frame, all_bone_keys["RL_Head"][frame]["x"])
  ```
- or just use `list` to retrieve simple keys list:

  ```
  for frame in list(all_bone_keys["RL_Head"]):
      print(frame, all_bone_keys["RL_Head"][frame]["x"])
  ```